# How could Chihiro eat food in the spirit world and not be transformed into a pig?

Tags: spirited-away

At the start of *[Spirited Away](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirited_Away)*, Chihiro's parents are transformed into pigs when they eat food in the spirit village.

Chihiro Ogino later eats a bun while seated on a balcony.

Why was she not transformed into a pig?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Chiriho's parents were turned into pigs because they kept eating food that was meant for the guests.

The food that she eats throughout the film was freely given to her, and in most cases intended for the staff at the bath house (which she becomes).

Comment: So the distinction is that her parents *took* food not meant for them, and she was *given* food that was meant for her?

Comment: @LincolnMan precisely. She works for Yubaba and earns her food. Her parents simply assumed that the food they saw was theirs to eat.